# Increment and then break and start over again based on a value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to increment a column and then stop and start again based on a value in another column.

For e.g:

I have a table:

```
CustomerID  YearMonth   True_False  
9000        2013-01-01   0
9001        2013-02-01   0
9002        2013-03-01   0
9003        2013-04-01   0
9004        2013-05-01   0
9005        2013-06-01   1
9006        2013-07-01   0
9007        2013-08-01   0
9008        2013-09-01   0
9009        2013-10-01   1
9010        2013-11-01   0
```

i want to achieve this:

```
CustomerID  YearMonth   True_False  Sequence
9000        2013-01-01   0            1
9001        2013-02-01   0            2
9002        2013-03-01   0            3
9003        2013-04-01   0            4 
9004        2013-05-01   0            5
9005        2013-06-01   1            0
9006        2013-07-01   0            1
9007        2013-08-01   0            2
9008        2013-09-01   0            3
9009        2013-10-01   1            0
9010        2013-11-01   0            1
```

So this is based on **True_False** column.
When **True_False** is 0 then break and start over again.
**Sequence** value for ( **True_False** = 0 ) doesn't need to be 0 could be NULL as well.

Comment: Order depends on which column?  CustomerID or  YearMonth ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CustomerID, YearMonth, True_False,
       CASE 
          WHEN True_False = 1 THEN 0
          ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY True_False, grp 
                                  ORDER BY YearMonth) 
       END AS Sequence
FROM (      
   SELECT CustomerID, YearMonth, True_False,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YearMonth) - 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY True_False 
                             ORDER BY YearMonth) AS grp
   FROM mytable ) AS t
ORDER BY YearMonth
```

The query calculates field `grp` which identifies islands of consecutive records having the same `True_False` value. Using this field in an outer query we can enumerate the records contained inside these islands and thus get the required sequence number.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/MLTGC30240)

Comment: Omg ty! Excactly what i needed!

Comment: Giorgio, I compare your solution with gordon and looks like your first secuence start with `1` and the rest with `0`. http://rextester.com/LNTY28841

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It's Gordon's query producing the result set with `0` is the sequence, not mine. My query has an alias, `Sequence`, for the last field.

Comment: Yes, I copy paste the wrong link http://rextester.com/WYCU75188 ... but you can see the difference on first row?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, I can see it. It's Gordon's query the one having the issue, not mine though. The OP wants every island of `0s` to *always* start with `1`.

Comment: You are right  my bad ... but that is a weird sequence :/.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think this is due to the first group not including a `1` record, whereas the rest of the groups do.

Comment: Yes, I miss that part in OP desire output. I assume he want the standard `0..n-1` index

Comment: Is it possible to group by customerid? Like if the customerid's to the left is 9001. And then the same data/rows for 9002 and so on...

Comment: @Blixter You can customize the way islands are populated and consequently enumerated. I need some sample data along with expected result so as to understand your actual requirement.

Comment: @Blixter Can you post the addendum as a separate question along with the expected result set?

Answer (score 5):

You want a row number inside a group of adjacent rows.  But you need to define the group.  It appears to be a cumulative sum of `true_false`.

So:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by grp order by year_month) - 1
from (select t.*, sum(true_false) over (order by year_month) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```